# ¿Por qué no visualizó componente vue, ni las modificaciones en vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Realice unas modificaciones en mio componente vue (categoria.vue) que lo tengo en la ruta /resources/js/components/Categoria.vue) para validar que los datos de categoria no estén vacíos pero al compilar el proyecto con npm run watch, y luego al correr el proyecto con php artisan serve no se visualiza el componente categoria.vue; adjunto mi componente Categoria.vue que muestra el código:

```html
<template>
   <main class="main">
            <!-- Breadcrumb -->
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active"><a href="/">BACKEND - SISTEMA DE COMPRAS - VENTAS</a></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Ejemplo de tabla Listado -->
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">

                       <h2>Listado de Categorías</h2><br/>
                      
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button" @click="abrirModal('categoria','registrar')">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Agregar Categoría
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <select class="form-control col-md-3">
                                      <option value="nombre">Categoría</option>
                                      <option value="descripcion">Descripción</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar texto">
                                    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Buscar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="bg-primary">
                                   
                                    <th>Categoría</th>
                                    <th>Descripción</th>
                                    <th>Estado</th>
                                    <th>Editar</th>
                                    <th>Cambiar Estado</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                               
                                <tr v-for="categoria in arrayCategoria" :key="categoria.id">
                                    
                                    <td v-text="categoria.nombre"></td>
                                    <td v-text="categoria.descripcion"></td>

                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md" v-if="categoria.condicion">
                                    
                                          <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i> Activo
                                        </button>

                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" v-else>
                                    
                                          <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i> Desactivado
                                        </button>
                                       
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" @click="abrirModal('categoria','actualizar',categoria)">

                                          <i class="fa fa-edit fa-2x"></i> Editar
                                        </button> &nbsp;
                                    </td>

                                    <td>

                                        
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                            <i class="fa fa-lock fa-2x"></i> Desactivar
                                        </button>
                                       
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                               
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <nav>
                            <ul class="pagination">
                                <li class="page-item">
                                    <a class="page-link" href="#">Anterior</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="page-item active">
                                    <a class="page-link" href="#">1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="page-item">
                                    <a class="page-link" href="#">2</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="page-item">
                                    <a class="page-link" href="#">3</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="page-item">
                                    <a class="page-link" href="#">4</a>
                                </li>
                               
                                <li class="page-item">
                                    <a class="page-link" href="#">Siguiente</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Fin ejemplo de tabla Listado -->
            </div>
            <!--Inicio del modal agregar/actualizar-->
            <div class="modal fade" :class="{'mostrar':modal}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-primary modal-lg" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title" v-text="tituloModal"></h4>
                            <button type="button" @click="cerrarModal()" class="close" aria-label="Close">
                              <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                       
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            
                            <div v-show="errorCategoria()" class="form-group row div-error">
                                
                                <div class="text-center text-error">
                                    
                                    <div v-for="error in errorMostrarMsjCategoria" :key="error" v-text="error"></div>

                                </div>
                            
                            </div>
                             

                            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="text-input">Categoría</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" v-model="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre de categoría">
                                       
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="email-input">Descripción</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="email" v-model="descripcion" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese descripcion">
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" @click="cerrarModal()" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i> Cerrar</button>
                            <button type="button" @click="registrarCategoria()" v-if="tipoAccion==1" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-save fa-2x"></i> Guardar</button>
                            <button type="button" v-if="tipoAccion==2" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-save fa-2x"></i> Actualizar</button>
                           
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div>
            <!--Fin del modal-->
           
        
        </main>
</template>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<script>
   
    export default {
        data(){

            return {

                nombre:'',
                descripcion:'',
                arrayCategoria:[],
                modal:0,
                tituloModal:'',
                tipoAccion:0,
                errorCategoria:0,
                errorMostarMsjCategoria:[]
            }

        },

        methods:{

           listarCategoria(){

               let me=this;

               const axios = require('axios');

               axios.get('http://localhost/proyectolaravel/public/categoria').then(function (response) {
                    // handle success
                    //console.log(response);
                    me.arrayCategoria=response.data;
                   
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    // handle error
                    console.log(error);
                });
           },

           registrarCategoria(){

               if(this.validarCategoria()){

                   return;
               }

               let me=this;

               const axios = require('axios');

               axios.post('http://localhost/proyectolaravel/public/categoria/registrar',{

                   nombre:this.nombre,
                   descripcion:this.descripcion

                   //'nombre':this.nombre,
                   //'descripcion':this.descripcion 
               }).then(function (response){
                   //handle success
                   //console.log(response);
                   me.cerrarModal();
                   me.listarCategoria();


               })
               .catch(function (error){
                   // handle error
                   console.log(error);

               }) 
           },

           validarCategoria(){
                  
              this.errorCategoria=0;
              this.errorMostarMsjCategoria=[];
              
              if(!this.nombre) this.errorMostarMsjCategoria.push("(*) el nombre de la categoria no puede estar vacio");

              if(this.errorMostarMsjCategoria.length) this.errorCategoria=1;

              return this.errorCategoria;



           },

           cerrarModal(){

               this.modal=0;
               this.tituloModal="";
               this.nombre="";
               this.descripcion="";

           },

           abrirModal(modelo,accion,data=[]){
                 
                 switch(modelo){

                    case "categoria":
                    
                    {

                        switch(accion){

                            case "registrar":

                                {
                                   
                                   this.modal=1;
                                   this.tituloModal="Registrar Categoria";
                                   this.nombre="";
                                   this.descripcion="";
                                   this.tipoAccion=1;
                                
                                }

                                case "actualizar":

                                {

                                
                                }
                        
                        }


                    }

                }

                        
           }
        
        },
        
        mounted() {
            //console.log('Component mounted.')
            this.listarCategoria();
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
        
     .modal-content{

      width:100% !important;
      position:absolute !important;
  }

  .mostrar{

      display:list-item !important;
      opacity:1 !important;
      position:absolute !important;
      background-color:#3c29297a !important;
  }

  .text-error{

      color:red !important;
      font-weight:bold;
      font-size:20px;

  }

</style>
```

Esta es la pantalla que había antes de mi proyecto cuando se ejecuta mi proyecto y llama al componente vue (categoria.vue)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es la siguiente ¿hay que hacer algo para confirmar en el archivo app.js de la carpeta /resource de mi proyecto de laravel para que se visualice los cambios que he realizado en mi componente vue categoria.vue?; que adjunto pantalla como sale ahora:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el archivo que llama a mi componente vue (categoria ve) el archivo que se llama "contenido.blade.php" que esta en la ruta /views/contenido/contenido.blade.php" en este caso de mi proyecto

```html
@extends('principal')
@section('contenido')
 
 <template v-if="menu==0">
 <h1>contenido 0</h1>
 </template>

 <template v-if="menu==1">
   <categoria></categoria>
 </template>

 <template v-if="menu==2">
   <h1>contenido 2</h1>
 </template>

 <template v-if="menu==3">
   <h1>contenido 3</h1>
 </template>

 <template v-if="menu==4">
   <h1>contenido 4</h1>
 </template>

  <template v-if="menu==5">
   <h1>contenido 5</h1>
 </template>

 <template v-if="menu==6">
   <h1>contenido 6</h1>
 </template>

 <template v-if="menu==7">
   <h1>contenido 7</h1>
 </template>

 <template v-if="menu==8">
   <h1>contenido 8</h1>
 </template>





@endsection
```

Estimado @Geimy Puse adjunto print de pantalla de que esta referenciado en el directorio de mi visual studioen el directorio que indicas c:\xampp\htdocs\proyectolaravel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y Así es como me sale ahora que no me carga mi componente vue (Categoría.vue) que esta en la ruta /resources/js/components/Categoria.vue

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código de mi archivo /resources/app.js es el siguiente:

```html
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key)))


Vue.component('categoria', require('./components/Categoria.vue').default);

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data:{
        
        menu:0
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola @Jose por lo que veo, no creo que esté mal el componente parece que es un problema de referenciarlo en el app.js, revisa si está bien escrito. Debería estar así:

```
Vue.component('categoria', require('./components/Categoria.vue').default);
```

Si en el caso contrario si está bien referenciado, revisa si estás compilando en la carpeta correcta.

Por ejemplo si estás en la carpeta

```
../xampp/htdocs/Dashboard
```

Revisa si estás también en el cmd en esa carpeta y recién ahí escribes

```
npm run watch
```

Espero haberte ayudado.
Fuente: Experiencia propia

Comment: Estimado @Geimy Puse si esta bien referenciado el componente en mi proyecto laravel en el archivo app.js de lo que te adjunto el código y print de pantalla de Visual Studios que es el seguiente Vue.component('categoria', require('./components/Categoria.vue').default);

Comment: Aya entonces revisa si estás en la carpeta correcta, te comento esto porque a mi me pasó lo mismo. Cuando agregas cambios no debes agregar algo más en app.js. Espero hayas solucionado. Saludos